# Creating/Embedding a Blog on an existing website

Tags: javascript, css, rss, blogs

I am looking to add a blog feature to a website template I am creating. It is basically a storefront template I am making for a company that will host stores for different artists wishing to sell their art on t-shirts, canvases, etc.

I am using software called InkSoft as the backend, which manages all the products, pricing, etc. I am using javascript and css to modify their built-in templates.

Inksoft allows you to create custom pages that you can modify with HTML. I would like to have a blog feature in the template so that the store owners (likely 100+ different stores) will be able to add news about products or whatever else they wish to display.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can implement this? Using wordpress or blogger doesn't seem feasible as there will be many store owners with many different domains, so it won't work to install wordpress on all of them and make them go to wordpress to add a post, etc. Maybe something with an RSS Feed...?

Thanks, let me know if you need any more details!

Rach

Comment: I like to use Tumblr for simple blogging functionality. You can easily point a subdomain like `blog.domain.com` to a Tumblog really easily with just a CNAME rule, with nothing to install. And you can even create a custom theme for the blog to match the original site. I'm not sure off the top of my head if Tumblr integrates RSS though...but I'd assume that they do

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to embed a blog page to a webpage with HTML assuming you can install something like WordPress to the website that will be hosting the stores.

```
<frameset id="frabody" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" cols="300,*">
<frame src="URL to the page you want to embed" name="Blog" id="Blog" noresize="yes" scrolling="Yes"
marginheight="100" marginwidth="0"
framespacing="0" frameborder="0">


</frameset>
```